# Вставная конструкция: "Девушка(,) а звали ее Катя(,) сказала в ответ..."

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, тире

По Розенталю, в редких случаях вставная конструкция выделяется запятыми: Мне показалось даже, *а может быть оно и в самом деле было так*, что все стали к нам ласковее (Акс.); Экспонаты Биологического музея, *а их свыше двух тысяч*, рассказывают о животном мире нашей планеты (Газ.).

- Возможно ли в предложении *Девушка(,) а звали ее Катя(,) сказала в ответ...* обособление вставной конструкции запятыми, или правильнее будет поставить тире: *Девушка — а звали ее Катя — сказала в ответ...*

Comment: А нужно ли вообще писать так сложно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая вставка лучше выглядит при обособлении запятыми, **что связано с наличием союза А:**

**Девушка, а звали ее Катя, сказала в ответ...**

Сравнить: **Девушка (звали ее Катя) сказала в ответ...**

Скобками лучше выделять вставные конструкции, которые содержат явно дополнительную информацию  и мешают пониманию основной части предложения. Также  скобки могут быть предпочтительнее с точки зрения графики.

Comment: А что скажете по поводу тире?

Comment: Розенталь различает  тематику скобок и тире, хотя иногда они бывают взаимозаменяемыми. Тире менее сильный знак, и он ближе к вводным словам и предложениям. Скобки ставят при заметном отступлении от темы предложения, при этом вставка может резко выпадать из синтаксической структуры предложения. Думаю, здесь как раз такой случай. Скобки хороши еще тем, что они обособляют только вставные конструкции, а тире - универсальный знак.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123